# Issue with inserting string into excel sheet

Tags: java, excel

I am trying to create an excel file which can have value as name and ID
  The lines which have made bol are giving me error in my program.Kindly help me out as what might be the mistake... pls
 If possible also help me out with the code of only writing name as in string into the excel file.

```
    package demos;
    import jxl.*;
    import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
    import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;
    import jxl.write.WriteException;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import com.sun.rowset.internal.Row;
    import jxl.CellView;
    import jxl.Workbook;
    import jxl.WorkbookSettings;
    import jxl.write.Label;
    import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat;
    import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

    public class StringInp 
    {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        try
        {
            String filename="C:\\virclipse\\input.xls";
    WritableWorkbook wb=Workbook.createWorkbook(new File(filename));

    //Create a blank sheet
    WritableSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Employee Data",0);

    //This data needs to be written (Object[])
    Map<String, Object[]> data = new TreeMap<String, Object[]>();
    data.put("1", new Object[] {"ID", "NAME"});
    data.put("2", new Object[] {101, "Shivany"});
    data.put("3", new Object[] {102, "Nalini"});
    data.put("4", new Object[] {103, "John"});
    data.put("5", new Object[] {104, "Ayush"});

    //Iterate over data and write to sheet
    Set<String> keyset = data.keySet();
    int rownum = 0;
    for (String key : keyset)
    {
    ***Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);***
    Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
    int cellnum = 0;

    for (Object obj : objArr)
    {
        ***Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);***

        if(obj instanceof String)
        {
     ***cell.setCellValue((String)obj);***
        }
    else if(obj instanceof Integer)
    {
    ***cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);***
               }
        }
    //Write the workbook in file system
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("filename"));
    wb.write();
    wb.close();
          } 
    }
    catch(WriteException e)
        {
        System.out.println("there is an error");
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the right imports but you need to have the required jxml jars in your build path also.

Comment: Thanks Juned but I have downloaded the jar file and inserted in my library... Still there is this issue....

Comment: @user3045921 You need to add jars to your build path. Here is the link you can follow to learn about it: http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java)

Answer (score 0):

you can [read here](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/), what is jExcel API here is a [tutorial](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html) also you can download API from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/files/jexcelapi/2.6.12/) please download jexcelapi_2_6_12.zip, after downloading extract it and put jxl.jar in your build path, those errors should go then

Comment: Thanks VD but I have already downloaded the jar file and inserted in my library... Still there is this issue....

Comment: Add it to your build path and export the same..(assuming you are getting compilation errors only)

Comment: you are using wrong Row(http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/rowset/com/sun/rowset/internal/Row.html) it doesn't have any method called createCell

Comment: Refer this(http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#writing) if you want to write into excel using jExcel API

Comment: here is a nice tutorial for using jxl API(http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaExcel/article.html)